# Fluid div next to fixed div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the [Bootstrap framework](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) for basis of the website.
Now, the main content is let's say is 1000px wide.
Then I have this 100% wide area, inside of which I have centered 1000px area.
But...

1. The left section is fixed width of 290px.
2. The right long section is fluid width and starts right from the border of the left section and it ends where the 100% wide container ends.
3. Inside of the right long section is 710px fixed content.

I want to have fluid width right content.
Image slider or google map or something.

I think the basic html should be:

```
<div class="wide_container">
 <div class="container1000px">
  <div class="left290px">
  </div>
  <div class="rightFluid">
   <div class="right710px">
     But inside of this the image slider should be wider than 710px.
     And this website is responsive, too.
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

[image: Some] ([Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZtBk.png))

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net for it

Answer (score 2):

set .rightFluid to min-width:710px and add class pull-right.

```
.rightFluid{
     min-width:710px;
}

<div class="rightFluid pull-right">
```

I think, this should work.

You can see reference here: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/B8L6L/

Comment: I don't see how this would work. The problem is that I have that 1000px container. Actually this 1000px container's width depends on the viewport size. As this is responsive website. I could rearrange the html. Important thing is that the left content is fixed width and should always align to the left - so it would align with the top header and below content's left line.

Comment: Let's say that there's no right710px div. Just that fluid. But it still would be limited if it's inside of that 1000px container. But the right content must start after left div and expand to right.

Answer (score 0):

for that u need to use structure like table -->

right-box will be fluid

```
<div class="table row-fluid">

    <div class="left-box"></div>

    <div class="center-box"></div>

    <div class="right-box"></div>

</div>

<style>

.table {
    display : table;
}

.table > .div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.left-box {
    width: fixed-with;
}

.center-box {
    width: fixed-with;
}

</style>
```

Comment: This would look like this - [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tt4E8/2/) - but I need Left to start where other content starts. That's why I have left and right inside of the container. It would also be aligned center then...

Comment: I made better image to explain my problem. Instead of that map could be image slider or whatever. [See image](http://i40.tinypic.com/2iivle8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

in that photo i saw u need fluid space for left side that i dont know what should be the rule for width (fluid  - something related to parent tag) , any way this link may be help u by extra little information about how this is work ,
[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/mehrabhk/CynZn/1/)

in that link u saw the gray part , that gray part is fluid , other color part got fixed width , in any table if u use fix width for some table-cell and leave other with out set any width they will fill remind width n if this answer is not helpful it must be misunderstanding from me of ur problem

```
.table {
    display : table;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;     
    background-color: #808080;
}

.table > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.right-box {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.center-box {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, finally found the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/LVx24/)

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="row hidden">
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell-centered">fixed width 600px; row in yellow just to show cell alignment, actually goes "hidden"</div>
<div class="cell"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
</div>
<div class="cell-fixed"><div class="fixed"><br>fixed width 200px<br><br></div></div>
<div class="cell relative">
<div class="outer absolute"><div class="inner absolute">100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100%</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {margin: 0; text-align: center;}

.table {width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 50px;}
.row {display: table-row;}

.cell {
background: #ccc;
display: table-cell;
width: 50%;
}

.cell-centered {
background: #aaa;
display: table-cell;
min-width: 600px;
}
.cell-fixed {
background: #bbb;
display: table-cell;
min-width: 200px;
}

.fixed {
background: #1dcf53 ;
width: 200px;
}

.hidden .cell {background: #f0ff00 ;}
.hidden .cell-centered {background: #e0ee00;}
.relative {position: relative;}
.absolute {position: absolute;}

.outer {
width: 100%;
padding-right: 400px;
right: 0;
}

.inner {
background: #1dcfa6;
width: 100%;
right: 0;
}

.container {
background: #eee;
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
margin: auto;
}
```